# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_balance'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

In my file named `Util_V2.py` I have created a function shown below:

```
from upstox_api.api import *
def get_balance():
    global u, s
    return u.get_balance()
```

where `u.get_balance()` is an inbuilt function in `upstox_api`.
When I try to call the above function in another file as in

```
a = (u.get_balance())
print(a)
```

it throws

> `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_balance'`

The same code is working in spyder, but not in pycharm.

The output data is dictionary.
What can be a problem here?

Comment: You never showed whether and what is assigned to `u` and where. Please provide a [repro]. Otherwise there is no way to tell what your problem is.

Comment: The [module you are using](https://github.com/upstox/upstox-python/blob/master/upstox_api/api.py) does not appear to define u and s. The Upstox class does - you most likely are supposed to instantiate it and use that.